# In order to apply a design on my object, should I texture it or model it?

Tags: modeling, texturing

This is my first real project on Blender. I need to create three decorative objects to a design class I have. I already done the "blocking" and texturing, but I cant solve two problems:

1. How to apply this tribal design over the object?
2. How to "engrave" the sun and moon into the objects?

[image: Models + reference]

[image: Paint job]

Can anyone enlighten me on this topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Textures for Details

I suggest [unwrap your object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/index.html) and create a black and white texture for all the details. This simple technique allows to apply different shaders to each part of the object and can be used for a normal map as well, *while* keeping the geometry nice and clean:

[image]

Further reading: [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: Did exactly what you said and it worked wonders. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Engraving something onto a surface using the knife project tool:

First, create the outline of the shape you want to create with vertices in a separate object:

[image: verts]

Then, in object mode, first select the shape, then the cup (or other object) behind it second, then go into edit mode:

[image: in edit]

Now, using the search menu, do a Knife Project, making sure the viewport points directly at the surface:

[image: done]

Now, you can just extrude the vertices on the cup inwards to create the engraving:

[image: done]

One note is that i used the auto-smooth feature under normals to remove any bad shading artifacts.

You'll need to be a little less vague on the second part. What do you mean by "apply the tribal design"?

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try later today.

I just added another image to the post. See those lines in the lower part of the cup, for exemple? Or on the backside of the mirror? I dont know how to "paint" it on the object without losing the texture of either the paint or the surface!

Comment: I took what you said and used it with the boolean modifier, since i couldnt find the Knife Project you mentioned, worked great!  Thank you!

Comment: no problem, the boolean modifier is definitely another good method, and even makes it more configurable later on.